# Disable http keep-alive on ASMX webservice

Tags: asp.net, web-services, connection, http-1.1

I have a .net webservice (old-school, not WCF) running on a website on IIS7.

I need to disable http keep-alive for the webservice, but not for the rest of the site.

Is it possible to override what IIS is doing here, just for that service?

I cannot change client code, which is calling in with http 1.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[See this link](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/httpProtocol)

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <httpProtocol allowKeepAlive="false" />
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Can you explain how that will satisfy my requirement to not disable keep-alives for the rest of the site?  Thanks.

Comment: Are you not able to extract the service to its own site?  I know you said you cant change the client code, but are you able to modify where it is pointing if you did that?

Comment: Unfortunately not - clients are pointing at a specific url which can't be changed.

Comment: I do not think there is a way to do what you want without involving IIS/a full application setting/changing client code to use HttpWebRequest (assuming .NET).  The only other thing I wonder if you could get away with is using an HttpModule to intercept that request then you could directly call the service with a HttpWebRequest to use the KeepAlive property.  However I have never done this, its just an idea.